# How do I make Heroku detect faye.js when using the Sync Gem for Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, faye

Here's my sync.yml:

```
production:
  server: "https://floating-springs-7322.herokuapp.com/faye"
  adapter_javascript_url: "https://floating-springs-7322.herokuapp.com/faye/faye.js"
  adapter: "Faye"
  auth_token: "44d3d241a5b4946a60caf1a6fc2e468b487cba51bf07f6ab88b1f6fd6b75c10b"
  async: true
```

As you can see, I'm using Faye as my pub/sub server.
Here's a link to the Github repository: https://github.com/19smitgr/real-time-test